# No internet on multiple computers

Tags: networking, wifi, windows-10

At the time, I am working as a sysadmin in a local school. In a specific classroom I have 28 Windows 10 workstations. All of them are connected to the internet via wireless through a single router. 4 out of all the computers refuse to connect to the internet. What could be the issue ?

Comment: I would say the downvotes here are for lack of information. I'd take a working machine and a non-working machine aside and see if you can find what is the same and what is different about them. Any settings that do not match, correct the non working machine to the settings on the working machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would check if they 1.) are connected via the right SSID, 2.) Are they getting IP addresses via DHCP. (Windows command prompt, the command ipconfig) 
If they do have IP's, can they ping the other computers, can they ping the router. 
After all that are they using the right DNS.